# Jquery UI loads after everything has loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I have been following a follow a youtuber's tutorial on JQuery UI for a while now, but here's the thing, every time I refresh the page, all of my html loads first then my CSS comes to fill in, so in that split second, you can see the HTML and CSS without the UI. Is there anyway I can prevent this, or is it normal for that to happen?

**Here's the HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

        <div class="header">

        </div>


        <div id="nav">


        </div>


        <div class="sidebar">

        <ul id="verticalMenu">
          <li><a href="">Rome</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Early</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Middle</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Late</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li>-</li>
           <li><a href="">Ancient Egypt</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Early</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Middle</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Late</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="">Ancient Greece</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Early</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Middle</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Late</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


              <div class="main">
                <div id="box">
                  <p>Thank you for visiting our site, we're hoping to see you again soon!</p>
                  <img src="ice.png">
              </div>


          </div>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**And JQuery UI**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){



    $("#verticalMenu").menu({
    menus: "div"
});

$("#box").dialog({

    title: "A thank you from us",
    autoOpen: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 300,
    show: 300,
    hide: 300,

    closeOnEscape: false,
    modal: true
});


  });
```

Comment: Do you mean you see the original UI (including CSS), and then after it applies jquery-ui menu?   You can move your scripts to the `<head>` to reduce this, but it's a standard issue called Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC) - you could hide your `#verticalMenu` until after the `.menu()` call or you can pre-apply the jquery styles to it.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easy way would be a `page loader`.
Position it fixed over the whole page and hide it on `document.ready`.

There are a lot of css examples out there... here is a pretty simple example. Not very beautiful but it does the job.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#verticalMenu").menu({
        menus: "div"
        });

      $("#box").dialog({

          title: "A thank you from us",
          autoOpen: true,
          draggable: true,
          resizable: false,
          height: 600,
          width: 300,
          show: 300,
          hide: 300,

          closeOnEscape: false,
          modal: true
      });


       $('.loading').fadeOut();

   

    });
```

```css
/* Absolute Center Spinner */
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* :not(:required) hides these rules from IE9 and below */
.loading:not(:required) {
  /* hide "loading..." text */
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.loading:not(:required):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


</head>

<body>
<div class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
  <div id="container">

        <div class="header">

        </div>


        <div id="nav">


        </div>


        <div class="sidebar">

        <ul id="verticalMenu">
          <li><a href="">Rome</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Early</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Middle</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Late</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li>-</li>
           <li><a href="">Ancient Egypt</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Early</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Middle</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Late</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="">Ancient Greece</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Early</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Middle</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Late</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


              <div class="main">
                <div id="box">
                  <p>Thank you for visiting our site, we're hoping to see you again soon!</p>
                  <img src="ice.png">
              </div>


          </div>

          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```